# how does java paint() method work?

Tags: java, applet, awt

I was expecting this applet to write x=0 and x=10, but it didn't :

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
/*
   <applet code="deney1" width=300 height=100>
   </applet>
   */
public class deney1 extends Applet {
    int x=0; // current position
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("x="+x, 0,20);
        x+=10;
        g.drawString("x="+x, 0,40);
        x+=1;
    }
}
```

What is going on here?

EDIT : It is proposed that my question is a possible duplicate of this one :

[how is paint() running without being called in the main method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764602/how-is-paint-running-without-being-called-in-the-main-method)

This post tells me that the paint() method will run without being explicitly called. But this doesn't explain the order in which the statements in paint() are executed, and I can't track the printed x values. Why not 0 and 10? Why not 11 and 22?
To make things a bit more clear :

```
g.drawString("x="+x, 0,20);     //  1
x+=10;                          //  2
g.drawString("x="+x, 0,40);     //  3
x+=1;                           //  4
```

It seems like : 2 and 4 are executed before 1 (x becomes 11). Then only 2 is executed before 3 (x becomes 21).

question 1 : Why 2 and 4 are executed before 1?

question 2 : Considering the answer to question 1, why 4 isn't also executed a second time before 3?

Comment: `awt` is out of date since `swing`. `swing` is out of date since `JavaFX`. This will not answer your question but is a good advice : never call it and use `JavaFX`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how is paint() running without being called in the main method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764602/how-is-paint-running-without-being-called-in-the-main-method)

Comment: Your code is ok, the problem should be somewhere else. Maybe in the main method.

Comment: Paint may be called for any number of reasons and my called a number of times within quick succession.  Assuming that the text got printed (which it did for me), `x` will be incremented by 11 each time that `paint` is called...

Comment: @WonderWorld Applets don't have a `main` method ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer no, but his program must have. Clearly this isn't all of the code.

Comment: @WonderWorld Why "must" it?  Applet's don't have a `main` method, they don't work that way.  All we know is the OP is expecting a result they aren't getting, but we don't know what they aren't getting...When I ran it, it work fine for me

Comment: @MadProgrammer  It prints x=11 and x=21. So, first increment is 11 but the second one is 10, not 11.

Comment: @onursurme Every time paint is called, you increment x by 10 + 1, so while my math is petty pathetic, that equals 11 in my book. The third time paint is called, it will print 32 & 33...

Answer (score 0):

This question is very popular :

[how does paint() work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977233/how-does-paint-work)

[why is my code executing paintComponent(Graphics page) twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814289/why-is-my-code-executing-paintcomponentgraphics-page-twice)

[Why does the paint method run twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661008/why-does-the-paint-method-run-twice)

[paint() in java applet is called twice for no reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067844/paint-in-java-applet-is-called-twice-for-no-reason)

http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/58131-help-yet-another-paint-called-twice-thread.html

At its first run, it prints x=0  x=10 , as I've expected. (x becomes 11 at the end of this first run).
Then paint() method runs again (this time starting with a x value of 11) and it prints x=11 x=21, which is the final view of the applet window.

**Proof :** you can add some code to pause the program for a few seconds after x+=1 , and when you run the program, first you'll see x=0  x=10, then it will change to x=11 x=21 .

**What to take home :** Write your paint() method as if it will run x times (you can't know x beforehand). So don't make your calculations in it.